How to reformulate the BigM constraints into its equivalent Convex-hull formulation?
I am trying to work on a scheduling problem based on its polyhedron reformulations. For that, I would like to reformulate a BigM model into its equivalent C-hull formulation. The transforming map is depicted in the following picture:

Now, the first thing coming to mind is that, Is it proven that always a C-hull formulation has better relaxation than a BigM or time-indexed formulation? Also, can we infer this may lead to reducing the solving process in a MIP?
Suppose there is a simple scheduling as of the form:
\begin{align*}
\text{minimize} \quad & s_1 + s_2 \\
\text{subject to} \quad & LB \leq s_1 \leq UB \\
\ & LB \leq s_2 \leq UB \\
\ & (s_1 \geq s_2+\alpha) \lor  (s_2 \geq s_1+\beta)\\
                        & s_1, s_2 \geq 0.
\end{align*}
It's linearized as:
\begin{align*}
\text{minimize} \quad & s_1 + s_2 \\
\text{subject to} \quad & LB \leq s_1 \leq UB \\
\ & LB \leq s_2 \leq UB \\
\ & s_1 - s_2 + (M+\beta)y_1 \leq M \\
\ & s_2 - s_1 + (M+\alpha)y_2 \leq M \\
\ & y_1 + y_2 = 1 \\
                        & s_1, s_2 \geq 0, y_1, y_2 \in \{0,1\}.
\end{align*}
and its C-hull equivalent would be:
\begin{align*}
\text{minimize} \quad & s_1 + s_2 \\
\text{subject to} \quad & s_1 = w_1 + w_2 \\
\ & s_2 = w_3 + w_4 \\
\ & LB \leq s_1 \leq UB \\
\ & LB \leq s_2 \leq UB \\
\ & y_1 + y_2 = 1\\
\ & w_1 - w_3 + \beta y_1 \leq 0\\
\ & w_4 - w_2 + \alpha y_2 \leq 0\\
\ & w_{i^s} - UBy_{i^d} \leq 0 ,\ \forall i \in I \\
                        & s_1, s_2 \geq 0, y_{i^d} \in \{0,1\}, w_{i^s} \geq 0.
\end{align*}
The second question is, is my transformation correct? (I can take the same objective value, but I would like to ensure I am not being lucky). Also, I am unsure what exactly the $w_1, w_2$ means.
I have tried to solve a large instance of the above formulation. In that case, it seems the BigM model has a better performance against the C-hull formulation. Maybe it is back to the internal mechanism of the modern MIP solvers to deal with BigM formulation rather than whose C-hull model!
May I have your insight?

Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4945400/how-to-reformulate-the-bigm-constraints-into-its-equivalent-convex-hull-formulat

Your proposed equivalent does not even mention $LB$, $UB$, $\alpha$, or $\beta$.

Dear @RobPratt, thanks. Actually, I missed adding the first two constraints from the first model into the second. Also, $\alpha $ and $\beta$ are two constants and are corresponding to $m_1, m_2$ in the second model.

The last constraint it incorrect as written; it would force $w_i=0$ for all $i$ since either $y_1$ or $y_2$ must be 0.

Rewrite as
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} & s_1 + s_2 \\
&\text{subject to} 
& (s_2 - s_1 \le -\alpha) &\lor (s_1 - s_2 \le -\beta) \\
&& \text{LB} \le s_i &\le \text{UB} 
\end{align}
Note that I have omitted $s_i \ge 0$, which is redundant to $\text{LB} \le s_i$.
The big-M formulation is
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} & s_1 + s_2 \\
&\text{subject to} 
& s_2 - s_1 &\le -\alpha + M_1 (1-\lambda_1) \\
&& s_1 - s_2 &\le -\beta  + M_2 (1-\lambda_2) \\
&& \text{LB} \le s_i &\le \text{UB} \\
&& \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 &= 1 \\
&& \lambda_j &\in\{0,1\}
\end{align}
The convex hull formulation is
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} & s_1 + s_2 \\
&\text{subject to} 
& s_1 &= t_{1,1} + t_{1,2} \\
&& s_2 &= t_{2,1} + t_{2,2} \\
&& t_{2,1} - t_{1,1} &\le -\alpha \lambda_1 \\
&& t_{1,2} - t_{2,2} &\le -\beta  \lambda_2 \\
&& \text{LB} \lambda_j \le t_{i,j} &\le \text{UB} \lambda_j \\
&& \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 &= 1 \\
&& \lambda_j &\in\{0,1\} \\
&& t_{i,j} &\ \text{free}
\end{align}
The interpretation is that $s_i=t_{i,j}$ when $\lambda_j=1$.
This formulation is not the same as what you proposed, even if you rename $\lambda_j$ as $y_j$ and the $t_{i,j}$ as $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4$.

Dear Rob, thanks for your reply. I just updated my question. Would you please, elaborate more on what you mentioned as This formulation is not the same as what you proposed, even if you rename λj as yj and the ti,j as w1,w2,w3,w4? Both seem very similar except in the defining LB on $w_i$ as I left it on default.

Also, may I have your insight regarding my other questions?

Check the signs of $w_i$ in your inequalities.

As the LB equal to zero is a valid LB for the original variables $s_1,s_2$, I defined the $w_i \geq 0$. Do you think it yields wrong results and I must define them as ($w_i = free$)?

I’m talking about the plus or minus signs of the constraint coefficients.

Ah, this is exactly what I was asking as my second question. I am actually not aware of that and I was wondering if you could say more about that.

For example, your $w_1$ is my $t_{1,1}$, and you have $w_1-w_3 \le -\alpha y_1$ whereas I have $t_{2,1} - t_{1,1} \le -\alpha \lambda_1$.

Dear Rob, I actually got your point about the difference between yours and mine. What I am looking for is why it should be $t_{2,1} - t_{1,1}$ and not being $t_{1,1} - t_{2,1}$? As far as I know, for each original variable in each disjunct, we should define its appropriate auxiliary decision variable. In my case, there are two disjuncts and in each one, there are two original variables. Then it needs totally four decision variables. Now, based on your first proposed model, the first disjunct starts with $s_2 -s_1$. Since their corresponding auxiliary variables are $t_{2,1} - t_{1,1}$

That means $s_2$ (in the first disjunct) - $s_1$ (in the first disjunct). If my intuition was correct the difference between your and mine comes from the difference between the linearization of bigm formulation. (I actually omitted my linearization for simplicity). May I have your idea?

Maybe adding your big-M formulation to your question will help clarify the discrepancy.

I just updated my question.

Your big-M formulation is correct but is weaker than the screenshot.  In particular, $\beta$ and $\alpha$ need not be multiplied by the $y_j$ variables.  Now that you have interchanged $\alpha$ and $\beta$, your convex hull formulation is getting closer, but you have too many inequality constraints.  The last one should not be $\forall i, \forall j$, which would yield $8$ inequalities instead of $4$.

Dear Dr. Pratt, thank you so much for your insight. Just out of curiosity, what actually is the benefit of the convex hull reformulation if we again need to deal with BigM constraints? Does it really provide a tighter relaxation? If so, why in large instances the BigM formulation seem to solve faster than whose c-hull? (Also, as I see in my instances the root node values in both cases are the same!)

Dear @RobPratt, may I have your insight regarding my last question in comment?
