Modeling the implication between pairs of Non-negative Continuous or Integer Variables
Say for instance, I have four positive or non-negative continuous or integer variables, $x$, $y$, $a$, $b$. I would like to ask about the constraints representing the following implications
i) $x\lt y \implies a \lt b$
ii) $a\lt b \implies x \lt y$
iii) $x \lt y \iff a \lt b$

Hint: introduce binary decision variable $z$ and enforce $x<y \implies z=1$ and $z=1 \implies a<b$.  See also https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/10172/how-to-enforce-logical-implication-sum-j-a-j-x-j-le-b-implies-sum-j-c-j-x-j.

Thank you for the hint, with reference to your link, as I am trying to enforce the strict < inequality, can I enforce it by changing say x<=y to x<=y-episilon, where epsilon is a small number say 10^-6?

Yes,. that is a common approach.  If the variables are integers, you can take $\epsilon=1$.

I understand such constraints are exactly not tight in nature, is there anyway to to reformulate them in a convex hull form as that in this link, https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/12276/how-to-reformulate-the-bigm-constraints-into-its-equivalent-convex-hull-formulat ?

The first disjunct, $(x \leq y \implies a \leq b)$, would be linearized as the following form:
\begin{align*}
\ x-y \leq M(1-z_1) \\
\ a-b \leq M(1-z_2) \\
\ z_1 + z_2 = 1 \\
\ Lb \leq x, y, a, b \leq UB \\
\end{align*}
To map disjunctions into their equivalent Convex hull, you need to define auxiliary variables to reformulate the problem. Also, as the original variables have a non-negative constraint, the $LB$ of the auxiliary variable can be left as default. By that, the Convex hull reformulation of the above disjunctions would be:
\begin{align*}
\ x = w^x + w^1 \\
\ y = w^y + w^2  \\
\ a = w^a + w^3 \\
\ b = w^b + w^4 \\
\ \\
\ z_1 + z_2 = 1 \\
\ Lb \leq x, y, a, b \leq UB \\
\ \\
\ w^x - w^y \leq 0 \\
\ w^a - w^b \leq 0 \\
\ \\
\ w^x - Mz_1 \leq 0 \\
\ w^y - Mz_1 \leq 0 \\
\ w^a - Mz_2 \leq 0 \\
\ w^b - Mz_2 \leq 0 \\
\ \\
\ w^1 \leq M(1-z_1) \\
\ w^2 \leq M(1-z_1) \\
\ w^3 \leq M(1-z_2) \\
\ w^4 \leq M(1-z_2) \\
\end{align*}
The procedure would be the same for the rest of the models.
Please, be aware that in many cases, specifically MIPs, there is NO guarantee to accommodate the BigM formulation into whose Convex hull equivalent with the aim of the reformulation, and it needs much more effort to take advantage of this reformulation. however, this reformulation causes a slightly slow convergence in the solving process.

Thank you. To the best of my understanding, convex hulls should provide the tightest relaxation, thus accelerating the solution process. I would hazard a guess that it is due to the additional decision variables that slow down the process. If that that is the case, could z2 be removed and just be replaced by 1-z1?. Or is the slower convergence due to other reasons? Thank you again!

convex hulls should provide the tightest relaxation, as a theoretical point of view, yes, But from the practical point, it depends on many other things. In a real problem and by reformulating it as CH, one actually injects much more variables and constraints into the model. I think this is the main reason for a slow convergence. could z2 be removed and just be replaced by 1-z1?, I never try that, so I cannot say any more.

Thank you for sharing.

Your big-M formulation enforces $x\le y \lor a\le b$ rather than the desired implication.
